# Spring Batch : How can we pre load values from DB and it will be used in processor section

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement where i need to lookup few tables in ItemProcessor section. I dont want to make multiple JDBC call for each row in the ItemProcessor section where it might lead to performance issue when the spring batch started to process more number of records. What are the workarounds to avoid this situation? is there any way to preload these objects before the ItemProcessor or before batch starts and can refer it in ItemProcessor ?

Comment: This is classic caching IMHO.  Assuming the data you are referring to is static, I'd just use typical service level caching.  If it is not static, then the issue becomes much more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch With Annotation and Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642796/spring-batch-with-annotation-and-caching)

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, i went through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642796/spring-batch-with-annotation-and-caching can you please explain bit more on how to implement this with a spring batch program and accessing it in ItemProcessor section ?

Comment: Thank you ! I have implemented caching in my spring batch based on your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotate your method with @PostConstruct to read data during the Spring application context initialization. Make your ItemReader's read method returns value from the list. When entire list is completed return null. This stops reading.

```
@Service
public class YourItemReader implements ItemReader<DomainObject> {

 private int index;

 List<DomainObject> dbRows;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
   List<DomainObject> //read from database
 }


@Override
public DomainObject read(){
        if (null != dbRows && index < dbRows.size()) {
         return dbRows.get(index);
       }
   return null;
}
```

If the number of records are in millions, I would suggest to do a chunk based read from your database instead of reading all the records at once which might case Garbage collector out of memory exception. This can be done easily by adding a column called STATUS to your table to track the status of the records that are processed. Initially when you load data to your table, set the status as 'NOT PROCESSED' and when your ItemReader reads the chunk of records set the status to 'IN PROGRESS'. Once your ItemProcessor or ItemWriter completes its processing, change the status from 'IN PROGRESS' to 'PROCESSED'. Make sure to make the method which fetches the data from the database as 'synchronized'. This will make sure multiple threads not to fetch the same data from database.

```
public List<DomainObject> read(){
 return fetchDataFromDb();
}

private synchronized List<DomainObject> fetchProductAssociationData(){
//read your chunk-size of records from database which has status as 'NOT 
PROCESSED' 
 and change the status of the data which is read to 'IN PROGRESS'
return list;
}
```